# Content type not support java Spring

Tags: java, spring, post

I have created a route

```
@RequestMapping( value = "login" , method = RequestMethod.POST ,  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE )
public void greet( @RequestBody  Login l){
    System.out.println(l.getName());
}

class Login{
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    private String name;
    private String password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }



    public Login(){};
}
```

And i am using postman to send data to it:

headers:

```
'Accept':application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

data:

```
name:Greet
password:Me
```

Yet i keep getting erorr:

```
"message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
```

I have read various questions and post about this but i fail to find solution to fix this.

All help is appreciated,  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring don't use `@RequestBody` annotation when consuming API with `Content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.

You have to use `MultiValueMap` in case of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: in that case  , the class is empty

Comment: use Map in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we use `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE` Spring does not understand it as a **RequestBody**. So remove **RequestBody** and do like this

```
@RequestMapping( value = "login" , method = RequestMethod.POST ,  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE )
public void greet(Login l ){
if(l != null /*or whatever you want to do*/)
    System.out.println(l.getName());
```

}